# Django rest framework group based permissions for individual views

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework, django-permissions, role-based-access-control

I am using DRF for writing API's. I would like to give different permissions for each view in my Modelviewsets. I have two groups(customers and staff). I have filtered them as Isstaff and Iscustomer in **permissions.py**.

```
class Iscustomer(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.groups.filter(name='customers'):
            return True
        return False


class Isstaff(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if request.user and request.user.groups.filter(name='staff'):
            return True
        return False
```

I am trying to overide using `get_permissions` method.
When I put a single group in `self.permission_classes`, it works fine.

```
class cityviewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = city.objects.all()
    serializer_class = citySerializer

    def get_permissions(self):    
        if self.request.method == 'POST' or self.request.method == 'DELETE':
            self.permission_classes = [Isstaff]
        return super(cityviewset, self).get_permissions()
```

But, when i try to put multiple groups in `self.permission_classes`, it fails.

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST' or self.request.method == 'DELETE':
        self.permission_classes = [Isstaff,Iscustomer,]
    return super(cityviewset, self).get_permissions()
```

Comment: What is it you mean by fail? Is there any error message??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is where you are adding multiple `permission_classes` to your views. The method where your `permissions` are checked is `check_permissions()`. If you look at the DRF code,

```
def check_permissions(self, request):
    """
    Check if the request should be permitted.
    Raises an appropriate exception if the request is not permitted.
    """
    for permission in self.get_permissions():
        if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
            self.permission_denied(
                request, message=getattr(permission, 'message', None)
            )
```

When you are providing multiple permission_classes, the user must satisfy both the permissions. So, the logged in user must be a Staff and Customer at same time. I think this is why your view fails.

Comment: I have added my answer. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply..Understood..Thank you.